# How to use sed command in Linux to replace this string?

Tags: string, replace, sed

I have many php files that have the following text:

"Title 1 / Subtitle 2 / Subtitle 3"

I need to replace this text by the following:

"Title 1 / Subtitle 3"

How do I do it using "sed" command?

Thank you.

Comment: Refer to the [sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.42).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
sed -i 's#Title 1 / Subtitle 2 / Subtitle 3#Title 1 / Subtitle 3#g' file*.php
```

#### Explanation

`sed 's#text#replace#g' file` replaces `text` with `replace` all alone `file`. If we add `-i`, it updates the file with the replaced version.